# How should I go about debugging a PHP Fatal Error?

Tags: php, wordpress

Since applying some updates to the server this morning, running certain wp cli commands returns a PHP Fatal Error.

An example would be...
wp cache flush

This worked yesterday, but now I get...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "WP_CONTENT_DIR" in /sites/www.mywebsite.com/files/wp-includes/load.php:115
Stack trace:
#0 /sites/www.mywebsite.com/files/wp-settings.php(37): wp_check_php_mysql_versions()
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1237): require('...')
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1158): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(23): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(74): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#7 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#8 {main}
  thrown in /sites/www.mywebsite.com/files/wp-includes/load.php on line 115
```

The code it references is the 2nd IF statement, in the following function...

```
function wp_check_php_mysql_versions() {
    global $required_php_version, $wp_version;
    $php_version = phpversion();

    if ( version_compare( $required_php_version, $php_version, '>' ) ) {
        $protocol = wp_get_server_protocol();
        header( sprintf( '%s 500 Internal Server Error', $protocol ), true, 500 );
        header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
        printf( 'Your server is running PHP version %1$s but WordPress %2$s requires at least %3$s.', $php_version, $wp_version, $required_php_version );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    if ( ! extension_loaded( 'mysql' ) && ! extension_loaded( 'mysqli' ) && ! extension_loaded( 'mysqlnd' ) && ! file_exists( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' ) ) {
        require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/functions.php';
        wp_load_translations_early();
        $args = array(
            'exit' => false,
            'code' => 'mysql_not_found',
        );
        wp_die(
            __( 'Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.' ),
            __( 'Requirements Not Met' ),
            $args
        );
        exit( 1 );
    }
}
```

I can see that it's checking php and mysql versions and having ran updates today, these may well have changed, which is why I'm getting the issue.

I've got WordPress set to log errors and it's logging other errors successfully, such as if I break the db connection info temporarily. The error messages in the function above don't appear to be getting displayed anywhere. I'd like to think that if "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress." was true, I'd be having much bigger issues than just wp cli commands not running.

It looks to me like the WordPress function isn't finding what it needs on the server, but that's about as far as my knowledge goes.

Would it be wishful thinking to hope more updates will be released tomorrow, which once installed, will make this issue go away?

I'm using mariadb, so for a newbie like me, it's adding extra confusion when the issue appears to be related to php and mysql version.

The issue is occurring on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, with both PHP 7.3 and 7.4.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an issue internal to Wordpress - it sounds though like you have a broken WP installation rather than a problem with Ubuntu.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. If it's effecting all WordPress sites across 6 servers and the core files haven't changed since everything worked, would that not mean it would have to be a permissions issue on the server, that had broken the WP installation?

Comment: Not necessarily, a permissions issue would be logged differently as a permission denied. you have a new problem of "undefined argument" - usually this is a Wordpress issue, especially if you haven't updated your Wordpress in a long while.

Comment: WordPress is updated daily on all sites, along with all plugins and themes etc.

Comment: I've just tried to create a new site and I'm getting a load of errors in trying to do so. I'll attempt to deal with those and hopefully it will rectify this issue. Thanks for taking the time to read and I'm guessing there's no magic tool. Sometimes undefined is all your getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the PHP version on the server, we had the same issue today due to this:

https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/j98i7s/ubuntu_ppa_installs_php_80rc1_automatically/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems PHP 8 was installed and possibly 7 removed.

I'd been running...
apt update
apt full-upgrade
apt autoremove

The following steps helped me revert this issue...

1. Take a backup of each site on the server to catch any changes today.
2. Restore server from backup.
3. Restore each site from this evenings backup.

Moving forward I'll just be running...
apt update
apt upgrade

Maybe it wasn't anything to do with my update commands though.
I've got a server that I'm about to delete, so didn't restore.
I ran the usual 3 update commands today and it appears to have fixed itself.
Maybe it wasn't wishful thinking to hope todays updates would have fixed my problems.